# Fragment crash: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm currently having a **crash on my app which I could only detect with Crashlytics** that has this stack:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.my.app/com.my.app.activities.SplashActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080048 (com.my.app.activities:id/container) for fragment l{453a70a8 #0 id=0x7f080048 FragmentXpto}
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2836)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2865)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2291)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:718)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080048 (com.my.app:id/container) for fragment l{453a70a8 #0 id=0x7f080048 DropboxFirstLinkFragment}
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:939)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1126)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(SourceFile:739)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(SourceFile:1489)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(SourceFile:434)
       at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onPostResume(SourceFile:115)
       at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5323)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2826)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2865)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2291)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:718)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

My Activities Layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"></FrameLayout>
```

I've check the Android source code and this is the throw where it is generated:

```
void moveToState(Fragment f, int newState, int transit, int transitionStyle,
            boolean keepActive) {
        // Fragments that are not currently added will sit in the onCreate() state.


...

   case Fragment.CREATED:
     if (newState > Fragment.CREATED) {
       if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "moveto ACTIVITY_CREATED: " + f);
          if (!f.mFromLayout) {
              ViewGroup container = null;
              if (f.mContainerId != 0) {
                container = (ViewGroup)mContainer.findViewById(f.mContainerId);
                  if (container == null && !f.mRestored) {
                     throwException(new IllegalArgumentException(
                                            "No view found for id 0x"
                                            + Integer.toHexString(f.mContainerId) + " ("
                                            + f.getResources().getResourceName(f.mContainerId)
                                            + ") for fragment " + f));
                                }
                            }
     ...
```

This is one of the issues which is reproducible only "once in a lifetime"... so I'm not passing the wrong id of the view, or anything like it, or it would crash frequently.

***More info:***

- I use a FragmentTransaction with replace on the onCreate method of the SplashActivity AFTER setContentView or on onResume:

  FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                          newFragment, tag);
  transaction.commit();

**Can somebody explain me why/when this can happen and how can I prevent it?**

Comment: Where is your fragment's xml view?

Comment: Could you tell us more about the crash? How were you able to reproduce it?

Comment: Check `R.id.container`, which not found

Comment: @D3LIC1OU5 I'm not. I only now it happens because I've received the report from crashlytics. It happened 1-2 time per version of my app.. which means its REALLY rare.

Comment: @Eenvincible Added the layout on the question.

Comment: @Xcihnegn I saw that... if I didn't have it it would crash always.

Comment: It would help if you post some code like the main Activity, at least. The bug is related to code and its layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've manage to avoid this issue by validating **if `findViewById(R.id.container) != null` and only doing the Fragment.replace on this case.**

**Whenever it is null, I store the operation, and retry it on the next onResume of the Activity.**

I think I've discovered the problem, as I've seen Fragments passing by onResume without having passed on the onCreateView when they were being restored, were not on the top of the FragmentManager stack and after the activity was killed on background.